# eval(document.getElementById("userinput").value) not working

Tags: javascript, html, input, eval

I have a input element that holds a `mathematical expression` in string form in its value attribute `(i.e "3+5-6*8")`

I want to evaluate this value and then set it as the new value for the input element.

this is my JS function:

```
    function evaluate() {
            document.getElementById("userinput").value=eval(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
        }
```

for some reason, this does not do anything

According to my knowledge, `eval()` only works if the argument is a string; otherwise it will return the argument unchanged.

The data type of the value attribute of the input element should be a string according to the way i made the input tag:

```
    <input type="text" id="userinput" readonly="true">
```

what is wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the evaluate function?

Comment: It appears _to me_ that you're just trying to set up a Cross-Site-Scripting attack test area.  Running `eval()` on end-user supplied data is a recipe for being pwned.

Comment: @StephenP: Why? It's an input, whose value is not set by a third party.

Comment: Also, how is the value of the input set if a) it's readonly and b) doesn't have a `value` attribute? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: If it is an `<input>` of any kind it is subject to tampering in-between the time it is sent to the client and the client (browser) sends it back to you. It could be subject to XSS or CSRF attacks, or a malicious end-user could modify it directly using Firebug or similar browser debugging tools. You **absolutely** cannot trust what is coming from the client and _always_ must treat it as potentially harmful. Anything in-between the client browser/IP-address and your webserver can modify it and turn it into something harmful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting the error: `Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The context node provided is null.`?

The problem is that `evaluate` is kind of a keyword that shouldn't be overridden: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

So I renamed the function to `foo`, and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/28sXE/1/

html:

```
<input type="text" id="userinput" />
<button onClick="foo()">do it</button>
```

js:

```
function foo() {
    var val = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    var out = eval(val);
    document.getElementById("userinput").value = out;
}
```

Comment: I think *you* got that error because you tried to use `evaluate()` in an [inline event attribute](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html). The OP doesn't seem to do this. The solution is not to rename the function, but to attach event listeners properly.

Comment: How do you know how the OP is attaching the event?

Comment: Well, we can't be sure as he didn't show us, but he did not seem to use an inline event attribute in his markup.